# Is there a special significance to the "20" on this Naruto/Kakashi shirt?

Tags: naruto, merchandise

I recently got this shirt and I was wondering if there was a special significance to the "20" on the shirt?

> [image: "KAKASHI 20" Naruto Shippuden T-shirt]

Comment: At a guess, the "20" might represent Naruto's publishing anniversary.  Although the ongoing manga chapters did not start until 1999, there was a pilot chapter in 1997

Comment: Related: [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Naruto/comments/9y83i0/does_the_number_20_have_significance_related_to/)

Answer (score -1):

The 20 on the shirt represents the age of Kakashi Sensei.

Comment: This is not correct. [Kakashi](https://narutoshippuuden.fandom.com/wiki/Hatake_Kakashi) is 26-27 in the original series, 29-31 in shippuden, and 51 in the Boruto series.